# How much time it will take to learn 3ds Max

Tags: 3dsmax

I am not a 3d developer but i want to lean 3ds max just for simple house building with 2-3 rooms. Actually i don't want to develop from scratch .

What i really want to do is get the existing models of homes , rooms , hotels from the internet and add my name there or my photo there , just for fun .

SO i want to know that how much time do u think it will take me to that sort of stuff.

Its not my career but just hobby . If its going to take longer time , then i don't want to waste but i can get going in one week or so that will go good but i want to ask from experience developers

thanks

Comment: Does this question actually belong here in its current form - or at all?

Comment: -1, I don't think this is an answerable question.  We have no idea of your experience or skill level.  And besides, couldn't you just find tutorials on what you want to do and just follow those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you need to learn more stuff about the general UI, and some basic 3D concepts. Only for that which you say, yes, a week if you are smart, dedicate time to it, etc. Two weeks I'd say. But uvmapping and texturing alone has its issues. Max has one of easiest GUIs for newcomers (more arguable if it being the most functional later on)

For modeling, not texturing, Google Sketchup is really great and easy, but the problem is the mesh export.

Another easy one for newcomers is Cinema4D. And a totally free one which would allow this mesh modifying matter, Blender.

Comment: u mean , creating 3dbuildings are more easier in cinema4d than max . For first step i want to create flag with **my name :)** on it and put it infront of any ready made model in max , any other soft. which software should i use :)

Comment: Any will do that. :) Cinema is very very easy and does nice renders without much knowledge needed. With Max is bit harder but you might have more flexibility. Blender's learning curve might be different as is basicly a different GUI to all the rest.
Doing a flag is attaching a strecthed prism with a plane attached as well, textured with a 2 sided material. Very easy. making it wave with the wind is quite harder ;). But pretty doable, also in Blender.